# Where to ask Facebook-related question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Stupid Facebook keeps telling me that my computer is infected so my account is temporarily blocked. I can't find a solution how to remove block.

Where can I ask this kind of question on the Stack Exchange network of sites?

Comment: I think in the first instance you should install and run some anti-virus and anti-malware software to see if your machine is in fact infected and if it is clean it up.

Comment: ChrisF I am using kaspersky internet security 2012 full version. It is the king of antiviruses.

Comment: Robert from where ? That is what i am looking for.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community where people that write Facebook applications can get help with _programming questions_. There is no Stack Exchange site devoted to supporting people _simply using_ Facebook.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG but that virus is also the king of viruses...

Comment: I don't understand why this question was down-voted so hard, even though it has useful answers?

Comment: This question, and this kind of questions, should not be downvoted at all. These are "where can I ask about ...?" and this network has dozens of sites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your particular situation *really* should be addressed to Facebook tech support, general questions about using (not programming for) Facebook are on-topic for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook).

Answer (score 24):

You have to ask Facebook this question, directly.  Facebook Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions only, and is not affiliated with Facebook Customer Support in any way.

http://www.facebook.com/help

Comment: Robert. I am not talking about stackoverflow. There are over 80 different parts of stackoverflow. I am asking which one is the most proper.

Comment: There are no SE sites available that can service your question. See the link I provided in my answer. SE is not all-inclusive; just because a question can be asked, doesn't mean there's a place on the SE network where it can be asked.

Comment: Robert Harvey i looked over there. There is no information about how to solve. You can check yourself and see yourself.

Comment: There's nothing we can do about that.  Call Mark Zuckerberg, and tell him how crappy his customer support is.

Comment: I thought there would be a network place for such questions at stackoverflow. So you are telling me there is no place

Comment: That's what I am telling you.

Comment: I might suggest SuperUser could help them determine if there's a virus, possibly. As in: [How do I know if I'm infected](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now) ...